# Targeting a clicked element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a button that toggles between making an img grayscale and normal. I need to find a way to properly target the button if it was clicked. I tried adding a class on click and then targeting that class. I also tried this.

```
$('.switch').on("click", function() {
    if($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
        $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
        $(this).siblings('img').css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(100%)");
    } else {
        $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)
        $(this).siblings('img').css("-webkit-filter", "none");
    }
});
```

Why the button doesn't toggle between color and grayscale versions?

Comment: What's the button `html` look like? Any console errors? jQuery being referenced correctly?

Comment: You have to provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue in order to get help

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the code you're showing us.

It looks like the problem is in your HTML, or in some part of your JS code that you aren't showing us.

#### Demo :

```js
$('.switch').on("click", function() {
    if($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
        $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
        $(this).siblings('img').css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(100%)");
    } else {
        $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)
        $(this).siblings('img').css("-webkit-filter", "none");
    }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<button class="switch" data-click-state="1">Switch</button><br/><br/>
<img src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/81bf1bd14d4465c89ca500001b22cf6e?size=140" />
<img src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/e711e151e517ae1b897898928cc7981c?size=140" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the toggleClass method. Add the styling to the css class.

Comment: OP's question is about why their click event isn't working the way they expect. This answer only provides an idea of how to do it differently.