# Targeting a clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpg8vcp0/)

I am trying to make a button that toggles between making an img grayscale and normal. I need to find a way to properly target the button if it was clicked. I tried adding a class on click and then targeting that class. I also tried this.

```
$('.switch').on("click", function() {
    if($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
        $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
        $(this).siblings('img').css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(100%)");
    } else {
        $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)
        $(this).siblings('img').css("-webkit-filter", "none");
    }
});
```

Why the button doesn't toggle between color and grayscale versions?
apparently the problem isn't in my jQuery but in my html, so is it not possible to use this jquery on a checkbox label?

Comment: in your demo the button switches what is the problem?>

Comment: The color doesn't change @guradio

Comment: i can see it changes from green to grey. what do you expect?

Comment: the image is supposed to go grayscale on first click then back to normal on second click

Comment: that we cannot see since you didnt put propery src on img.

Comment: the first image should be showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press the button once, it detect two clicks. I set an alert outside the if statement and I would get it twice per click, so your problem lies with that.

I'm still inspecting it, but that the issue right now, need to figure out why it is occurring, will update.

Update:
Yes sir, that was the cause that I stated in the comments... Here is a fixed, and you can mess with it however you like.

```
$('#cmn-toggle-1').on("click", function() {
    if($(this).attr('data-click-state') == '1') {
        $(this).attr('data-click-state', '0')
    $(this).parents().siblings('img').css("-webkit-filter", "grayscale(100%)");
    }  
   else {
    $(this).attr('data-click-state', '1')
    $(this).parents().siblings('img').css("-webkit-filter","");
   }
});
```

New HTML SNIP:

```
<div class="switch">
    <input id="cmn-toggle-1" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-yes-no" type="checkbox" data-click-state="1">
    <label for="cmn-toggle-1" data-on="Color" data-off="B&W" data-click-state="1"></label>
</div>
```

As you can see if you look at the input, I added in the `data-click-state="1"`

Comment: On the first image I have data-click-state="1" not sure if that is why. But when I asked this question before and only gave my jquery code, someone set up a working demo like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35949527/targeting-a-clicked-element-with-jquery/35949621#35949621

Comment: One thing I have notice is that you use the click listen attached to your div. In that div you have two element, it possible that you are clicking both elements and that is why it is running twice.

Comment: now It is working excpet that I need to click twice before the grayscale will happen. Do you know how I can fix that too? Nevermind i was able to fix it myself. Thank you

Comment: Yes sir, basically since it is checking #cmn-toggle-1 for the data-click-state attr, but it is not included at initialization, you'll have to add it in. I left that out so you can work with it however you needed to make edits now that you know what the issue is. I will update my question in a second..